# Where are all the places that VBA macros for Excel 2007 can be turned off?

Tags: security, excel, excel-2007, windows-server-2003, vba

Macros refuse to run for me in Excel 2007 on Windows Server 2003.
The macro and visual basic icons on the ribbon are grayed out.
If I open a workbook with a macro, I get the warning: " This workbook has lost its VBA project, ActiveX controls and any other programmability-related features."
If I try to make a new excel template in VSTO (Excel is closed at the time), I get the error: "Programmatic access to the Microsoft Office Visual Basic for Applications project system could not be enabled. . ."

I checked that VBA was installed (originally it wasn't, I added it via office setup).  I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling office and VBA, no dice.
I made a macro-enabled workbook.
I set the workbook's location to trusted.
I configured all of the security settings available under Excel Options/Trust Center to allow-everything-no-prompts.
I set "Enable all macros" and "Trust access to the VBA object model".
I downloaded the group policy admin templates and verified none of this is being set via group policy.

That's everything I can find in Google to try, but clearly there is another place that VBA can be turned off.  Where else can I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't a system policy in place that inhibits VBA?

Edit: Some reading, if you've not already seen these:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282847/en-us

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287567

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281954/en-us - Applies to earlier versions, but some/all may still be relevant to 2k7

Answer (score 0):

Alt+F11 in excel and see if there is an option in there that you can change....